# Spring sleuth error - correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud-sleuth

When I start my spring boot application, I am running into this error below.

Any help is highly appreciated.

> An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt
> was made from the following location:
>
> org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.TraceAutoConfiguration.sleuthCurrentTraceContextBuilder(TraceAutoConfiguration.java:205)
>
> The following method did not exist:
> 'brave.propagation.CurrentTraceContext$Builder
> brave.propagation.ThreadLocalCurrentTraceContext.newBuilder()'
>
> The calling method's class,
> org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.TraceAutoConfiguration,
> was loaded from the following location:
>
> jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/7.3.1/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/2.2.2.RELEASE/efadbe4d0d8f3535723bc638109098e691fadc91/spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceAutoConfiguration.class
>
> The called method's class,
> brave.propagation.ThreadLocalCurrentTraceContext, is available from
> the following locations:
>
> jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/7.3.1/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.zipkin.brave/brave/5.13.2/8b44454a5712e049d2e0d189d8102c53263db240/brave-5.13.2.jar!/brave/propagation/ThreadLocalCurrentTraceContext.class
>
> The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following
> locations:
>
> brave.propagation.ThreadLocalCurrentTraceContext:
> file:/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/7.3.1/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.zipkin.brave/brave/5.13.2/8b44454a5712e049d2e0d189d8102c53263db240/brave-5.13.2.jar
> brave.propagation.CurrentTraceContext:
> file:/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/7.3.1/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.zipkin.brave/brave/5.13.2/8b44454a5712e049d2e0d189d8102c53263db240/brave-5.13.2.jar
>
> Action:
>
> Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains
> compatible versions of the classes
> org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.TraceAutoConfiguration and
>
> brave.propagation.ThreadLocalCurrentTraceContext\n","@version":"1","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter","thread_name":"main","level":"ERROR"}

My build.gradle

```
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'project-report'
}

group = 'com.abc.xyz.eds'
version = '0.17.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "https://wells.jfrog.io/wells/wells-maven"
        name "wells-central"
        credentials {
            
        }
  }
    maven {
        name 'wells-snapshots'
        url 'https://wells.jfrog.io/wells/wells-snapshots'
         credentials {
            
        }
        mavenContent {
            snapshotsOnly()
        }
    }
    maven {
        name 'wells-releases'
        url 'https://wells.jfrog.io/wells/wells-releases'
        credentials {
            
        }
        mavenContent {
            releasesOnly()
        }
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.0'
    }
    applyMavenExclusions = false
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation 'redis.clients:jedis:2.9.0'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    implementation 'ca.uhn.hapi.fhir:hapi-fhir-structures-r4:5.4.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.12'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:2.2.2.RELEASE'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic'
    implementation 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.6'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    implementation ('com.wells.magnify.jiraboard:support-client:3.11.0-SNAPSHOT'){
        exclude group: 'com.wells.platform', module: 'tenant-contract'
    }

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    implementation ('com.wells.magnify.eds:eds-common-authorization:1.0.2'){
        exclude group: 'com.wells.rapid.commonlibs', module: 'organization-keys'
    }
    implementation 'com.wells.rapid.commonlibs:rapid-key-interface:1.0.0'
    
    testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'com.wells.magnify.eds:eds-common-code:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.490'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.SR3'
    
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.23.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.21.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.vintage', name: 'junit-vintage-engine', version: '5.3.2'
  testImplementation group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-runner', version: '1.2.0' 

}

bootRun {
    String activeProfile =  System.properties['spring.profiles.active']
    systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", activeProfile
}

springBoot  {
    buildInfo()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

    testLogging{
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
    maxHeapSize = '1G'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the cloud BOM 2021. Why are you setting sleuth version manually? Just remove the manually set version and you're done

Comment: Now I get the below error 

```Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.ExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(java.util.concurrent.Executor, org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory)'
```

Comment: On further research I see that one ExecutorMethodInterceptor.class is coming from ```spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar``` and another from ```spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation:3.1.0```

Comment: Yes that's because you're setting the values manually. Please do not do that, just use the BOM. Because you're doing it you have a version mismatch. Can we mark this as answered?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have put a version for sleuth dependency :

> 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:2.2.2.RELEASE'

Please try by removing the version for this dependency and let gradle resolve the compatible version of sleuth corresponding to the Spring Boot version you are using.